# How to open multiple password protected excel files using VBA and copy and paste the data within the password protected files into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, automation, password-protection

So in my worksheet, I have a table which has the filename, the path of the file and the password associated with the file.

I wanted to be able to open all these files by automatically by inserting their relevant passwords copy all the data in these files and paste them into another worksheet in my file called Output and close them down.

I have given the column (N) which has my filenames the named range: FileNames
I have given the column (O) which has the path of each of my files the named range: Paths
I have given the column (P) which has my the password for each file the named range: Passwords

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub OpenPwdProtFiles()


ict = 0
Set FileNames = Range("Filenames")
Set paths = Range("Paths")
Set passwords = Range("Passwords")
Set CornerCell = Range("CornerCell")

For Each Filename In FileNames
    ict = ict + 1
    If Filename.Text <> "" Then
        Filename.Copy
        mypath = paths.Item(ict).Value
        mypwd = passwords.Item(ict).Value
        'Open workbook mypath, fname, password
        'Copy contents
        'Move down to latest unpopulated row on Output tab and paste
        Set cell2paste = CornerCell
        OutputSheet.Activate

        cell2paste.xlDown.Offset(1, 0, 0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
Next



End Sub
```

I am having a problem with the  `OutputSheet.Activate` part as it keeps saying Object required but and I do not know wat to do as it has been a while since I have done some VBA coding. So I would appreciate if anybody could help me out

Comment: Is `OutputSheet` the *codename* of a worksheet? Otherwise you need something like `Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OutputSheet")`.

Comment: I have a sheet called Output which is where I am trying to paste the data

Comment: Then add `Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")`

Comment: Thanks for that. I now get an error saying "Object does not support this property or method" and it has to do with the code: `cell2paste.xlDown.Offset(1, 0, 0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: No need to assign CornerCell to a separate range, and xlDown is part of the Range.End options; `CornerCell.End(xlDown).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`